# Multiple sliders on one page: How to make arrows target a specific set of slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this, each

I am trying to create a portfolio site that contains multiple image sliders on the same page. I had the HTML, CSS & jQuery working for a single slider, but as soon as I added another--with the same classes--things got funky.

My question: how can I make the left & right arrows only target the slides that they are connected to?

Potential fixes:

-Do I need to reorganize the HTML to make the arrows siblings with the slides? They are already contained in the same "portfolio-item" div, though.

-Do I need to be using "this" and/or "each in jQuery? I've tried using the "this" and "each" selectors in different spots, but no luck. I am new at this, so I could have been using them wrong.

The code attached is working, but the arrows are moving all the images in the document, not just the ones on their respective slider.

Thank you for your help!!

Ryan

```js
var main = function(){
 
 $('.slide:first-child').fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    
 //right arrow!
 
    $('.portfolio-item .right-arrow').click( function(){
        var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
        
        if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
            nextSlide=$('.slide:first-child');
        }
        
        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
        
    });
    
 //left arrow!
 
    $('.portfolio-item .left-arrow').click( function(){
        var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
        
        if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
           prevSlide=$('.slide:last-child');
        }
        
        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        
 });
    
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.slider-container {
 display: block;
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 max-width:600px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0% 0% 1% 0%;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:left;
}

.slider {
 position:relative;
 padding-top: 45%;
 z-index:0;
}

ul.slides {
 z-index:1;
 list-style-type:disc;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.active-slide {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.slide {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.slide img{
 margin:0;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 z-index:2;
 left:0;
}

.arrow {
 position:absolute;
 top:42%;
 width:5%;
 opacity: 0.7;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   z-index:3;
}

.left-arrow {
 left:1%;
}

.right-arrow {
 right:1%;
}

.arrow:hover {
 opacity:1;
 cursor:pointer;
}

@media (max-width:886px) {
.slider-container {
 max-width:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>


<body>


<div id="content">
  
        
        
        
        <div class="portfolio-item" id="woll">
            
       <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider"></div>
                    
               <img class="arrow left-arrow" src="http://authenticid.co/img/leftarrow.png" />
            <img class="arrow right-arrow" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png" />
                        
        <ul class="slides">
    
         <li class="slide img-1"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll-brainstorm.jpg?w=986&h=632&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="slide img-2"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll-spread.png?w=521&h=658&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="slide img-3"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll_empowerment-email.png?w=461&h=658&crop=1"></li>
    
        </ul>

         </div>
            
     </div>
        
        
                
        
        <div class="portfolio-item" id="jennyandshawn">
            
       <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider"></div>
                    
                    <img class="arrow left-arrow" src="http://authenticid.co/img/leftarrow.png">
           <img class="arrow right-arrow" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/N/a/Q/C/n/white-arrow-right-md.png">      
    
        <ul class="slides">
    
         <li class="img-1 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-wedding_small_1.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-2 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-save-the-date.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-3 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-table-number.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-4 slide"><img src="Jenny&Shawn/138.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="img-5 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/138_21.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
    
        </ul>
     
         </div>
            
     </div>
        
        
        
        
</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should contextualize where are you working with jquery like this

var currentContext = $(this).closest('.slider-container');

because right now, when you do : var currentSlide=$('.active-slide'); in reality this selects the two active sliders, and you only want to activate the one that you clicked.

```js
var main = function(){
 
 $('.slide:first-child').fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
    
 //right arrow!
 
    $('.portfolio-item .right-arrow').click( function(){
        // this saves context
        var currentContext = $(this).closest('.slider-container');
        // this select active-slide of the context
        var currentSlide= currentContext.find('.active-slide');
        
        //var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide=currentSlide.next();
        
        if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
            //nextSlide=$('.slide:first-child');
            // this selects the next slide of the context
            nextSlide= currentContext.find('.slide:first-child');
        }
        
        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
        
    });
    
 //left arrow!
 
    $('.portfolio-item .left-arrow').click( function(){
        // this saves context
        var currentContext = $(this).closest('.slider-container');
        // this selects the current active slide of the context
        var currentSlide= currentContext.find('.active-slide');
        
        //var currentSlide=$('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();
        
        if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
           //prevSlide=$('.slide:last-child');
           // this selects the previous slide of the context
           prevSlide= currentContext.find('.slide:last-child');
        }
        
        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
 });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.slider-container {
 display: block;
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 max-width:600px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0% 0% 1% 0%;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:left;
}

.slider {
 position:relative;
 padding-top: 45%;
 z-index:0;
}

ul.slides {
 z-index:1;
 list-style-type:disc;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.active-slide {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.slide {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.slide img{
 margin:0;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 z-index:2;
 left:0;
}

.arrow {
 position:absolute;
 top:42%;
 width:5%;
 opacity: 0.7;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   z-index:3;
}

.left-arrow {
 left:1%;
}

.right-arrow {
 right:1%;
}

.arrow:hover {
 opacity:1;
 cursor:pointer;
}

@media (max-width:886px) {
.slider-container {
 max-width:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
        <div class="portfolio-item" id="woll">
       <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider"></div>
               <img class="arrow left-arrow" src="http://authenticid.co/img/leftarrow.png" />
            <img class="arrow right-arrow" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_right_alt1-512.png" />
        <ul class="slides">
         <li class="slide img-1"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll-brainstorm.jpg?w=986&h=632&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="slide img-2"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll-spread.png?w=521&h=658&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="slide img-3"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/wollwoll_empowerment-email.png?w=461&h=658&crop=1"></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
        
        <div class="portfolio-item" id="jennyandshawn">
       <div class="slider-container">
     <div class="slider"></div>
                    <img class="arrow left-arrow" src="http://authenticid.co/img/leftarrow.png">
           <img class="arrow right-arrow" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/N/a/Q/C/n/white-arrow-right-md.png">      
    
        <ul class="slides">
         <li class="img-1 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-wedding_small_1.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-2 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-save-the-date.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-3 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/jenny_shawn-table-number.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
            <li class="img-4 slide"><img src="Jenny&Shawn/138.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="img-5 slide"><img src="https://ryanachtman.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/138_21.jpg?w=1000&h=&crop=1"></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```